# How to send a HttpWebResponse object (containing image data) on server side to client (jquery/javascript) and display the image on UI?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario where following code is there on the server side.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SomeUrl");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The response here contains some image data.

I wish to send this image data to client side and display the image there.
How can I accomplish this and What would be the best way to do that.

Please help on this.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is supplying an `<img>` with the `src` attribute pointing to that action not feasible? That would be the easiest way.

Comment: There are plenty of similar answer in here. Look for byte  array to base 64 string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one bite at the response apple. Either you return an image directly or you return HTML that includes an `<img>` tag that points to that image. You can't do both.